# Coldfusion ORM relationship id list

Tags: orm, coldfusion, many-to-many

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to get an ID list of all the target objects relating to a source object in a coldfusion component using ORM?

I can see that you can do a collection mapping for one-to-many relationships, but I am using many-to-many relationships. I don't want to have to get the array of objects and then loop over it to get each id.

Is there any built in function or property that could do this?

I think something like the code sample below is a little too heavy since it is getting the whole query and then getting a single column from it.

```
valuelist(  EntityToQuery( object.getRelationalFields() ).id  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [ORMExecuteQuery](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSfd7453be0f56bba45b6e22cb12308efc3aa-8000.html) may work for you, something like this:

```
result = ORMExecuteQuery("select id from Model as m where m.parent.id = :id", {id = 123});
```

*Actual clause format depends on the relationship definition.*

In a `result` you'll have the array of model PKs.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it doesn't make sense to use ORM, and this is the time.  Use the good old `<cfquery>` for this!